# What does this sentence mean? "if you just push in here to see.."

Tags: meaning

The sentence is from what a reporter said in the CNN news and I don't quite understand what that means. The whole thing is like this following.

> But here, people are describing this as devastating, catastrophic,
>   historic even worse than what they saw back in July of 2016, that this
>   flooding happens, so rapidly, so quickly, that it just lifted cars and
>   just had the water gushing down main street, catapulting into
>   buildings, buildings collapsing, people just simply running for their
>   lives. Still, **if you just push in here** to see the aftermath of the
>   devastation, I had a chance to talk to one of the officials here who
>   said that there`s one person that is missing, hopefully they are OK.

When I look up for "push in" in a dictionary, I found that it means "to rudely join a line of people who are waiting for something, by moving in front of some of the people who are already there:" But if it does, I don't think the sentence is quite going with the flows overall.

Could anybody please help explain what she meant by "push in here to see" to me? 
Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: It suggests that getting "in here", may have required some effort, or difficulty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best educated guess is that it's referring to camerawork. The quote you have comes from a [transcript of a video](http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1805/29/sn.01.html). It sounds from the context like the speaker is making a request to a camera operator or editor. With that in mind, I looked up cinematography techniques and found [The Push Technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkvO1vSk0nY&vl=en). That seemed to be on the right track, but that's for movies, not news. I looked at photojournalism websites and found [Commonly Used Terms in Television Journalism Flashcards](https://quizlet.com/163100218/commonly-used-terms-in-television-journalism-flash-cards/). The "push in" is:

> When a photographer goes from wide shot of a subject to a closer shot of the same subject all in the same shot on a recording. often used when the subject says something emotional.

So, it sounds like CNN correspondent Suzanne Malveaux is asking her camera operator to zoom in on a section of a still or moving image to highlight the devastation of the flood. As far as I can tell, it's industry-specific language.

Comment: That sounds plausible.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It really helped.  :)